# Compile Fortran source with Accelerate Framework (LAPACK and BLAS)

Tags: macos, makefile, frameworks, fortran

I wish to compile `Fortran` source code which uses functions from `LAPACK` and `BLAS`. When I compile a single source code file e.g.

```
gfortran -g -framework accelerate test.f
```

*it works*.

However, I have many source code files which I want to compile through `Makefile`. When I modify my `Makefile` by adding:

```
LDFLAGS= -framework Accelerate
```

> (Not sure it is the right way but that's how someone seemed to do it)
>   I get the error that the lapack function used inside is unrecognized.

Can someone tell me what modification to do in the makefile?

Here is the error I get:

```
gfortran -g test.o  -o a.out
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_sgesv_", referenced from:
     _MAIN__ in test.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [a.out] Error 1
```

sgesv is the lapack subroutine being called which shall be included in veclib/accelerate framework.

Here is the copy of my Makefile:

```
#
#              
#
#FFLAGS = -fast
#FFLAGS = gfortran
FC = gfortran
LFLAGS = gfortran -g
LINK = gfortran -g
LDFLAGS = -framework Accelerate
OBJECTS = test.o\

SOURCES = test.f\

a.out:  $(OBJECTS)
    $(LINK) $(OBJECTS) -o a.out
```

For others:

Here was what I was doing wrong. The last line should change:
       $(LINK) $(OBJECTS) -o a.out $(LDFLAGS)

Comment: Perhaps post the exact error message you are receiving.

Comment: Isn't capitalization important (notice `accelerate` and `Accelerate`)? You definitely have to post the error message.

Comment: @Vladimir F, I don't think the capitalization matters here. But just to make sure I changed both to lower and upper case and even tried the example I run from terminal both ways too. It works regardless.

Comment: Show your Makefile, ho is $LDFLAGS used there? Notice that you do NOT have any accelerate in the link command in your error message. You must get it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler tells you that it cannot find `sgesv`, which is (in your case) part of the accelerate framework. From the error message, I see that the command resulting from the Makefile is

> ```
> gfortran -g test.o  -o a.out
> ```

which is missing the linker directive.

So, within the Makefile you are missing the link flags in the actual command:

```
a.out:  $(OBJECTS)
    $(LINK) $(OBJECTS) -o a.out $(LDFLAGS)
```

Comment: Added it. Same error.

Comment: Can you see the framework directive in the command/error message?

Comment: This works. @Alexander Vogt There was a typo in the original makefile.

Comment: I did now. Sorry new to this website. You guys are awesome. Also, I see now that the question has been answered elsewhere too. Shall I delete this now? Also, the other question is not something that I came up to as a noob.